# Failed to restart the ADB server. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.MaybeStartupAdbServerDeployer) on Ubuntu

Tags: adb, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am getting error while deploying Oracle MAF application on android device. My error is mentioned in the image below: 
I have already tried

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb restart
```

But i am not getting the solution.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZU87.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to occur when Android SDK Platform Tools are updated to the latest version(Currently 27.0.1). Reverting to an older version will fix this.

I am currently on version 25.0.6. and am able to deploy to Android successfully.